# netstat is not showing port opened through ufw

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, ftp, ufw

I am setting up a ftp server on my Ubuntu 16.

After using the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow 21/tcp
sudo ufw status verbose
```

I can see the output that says:

> 21/tcp    ALLOW    IN    Anywhere

But, if I type:

```
netstat -tnlp
```

It does not show the port 21 at all

Do I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`netstat` will only show the port if a service or other program is actually listening for incoming connections *on* that port.  Is your FTP service running?

Comment: It seems that vsftpd is not working at all. When I run netstat -a | grep ftp ti does not show vsftpd

Comment: Also, i tried: sudo service vsftpd start and after hitting ENTER I dont get any output that says the service is running or the PID.

Comment: That's why netstat shows what it does, then.